# Detect dots in a image using image processing with python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-enhancement

I need to identify the following dots in the given images. But it doesn't give correct detection. Can someone give a methodology to identify these dots in an image like this?
[image]

I have done some enhancement to this as follows,
[image]

- enhanced image, by dilation followed by sharpened

  I Used template matching for detecting these dots in the image. But it didn't work well. Code is as follows. Is there any other way to detect these?

import cv2
import numpy as np

```
img_rgb = cv2.imread(file)
cv2.imwrite("D:/4/Detect/"+str(i)+".0.jpg",img_rgb)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template = cv2.imread('a.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.455
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,255,255), 0)

cv2.imshow('Detected',img_rgb)
cv2.imwrite("D:/4/Detect/"+str(i)+".1.jpg",img_rgb)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: please share the  [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I used a template maching for this but it doesn't work much. When using a template it detects some nonrelated parts as well. Is there any other way to detect these?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the main part of the code for better result (shown in the image below), that I developed quickly:

```
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('med.jpg',0)
th2 = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
            cv.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
th3 = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
titles = ['Adaptive Mean Thresholding', 'Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding']
images = [th2, th3]
inv = ~th3
res = cv.bitwise_and(img,inv)
cv.imshow(titles[1],res)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.imwrite("result.jpg",res)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

**Tune the parameters for desired result.**

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply SKG. Actually, I worked with adaptive thresholding, canny, morphological operators so many types but I need to segment the dots only. In the above image also, it segmented the dots together with other elements as well. The requirement is only dots. Is there any way to do it? Thank you in advance

Comment: From my output, do blob-analysis. There you will get all the statistics (measures) of the blobs. Now with thresholding you can keep the desired blobs & reject the undesired blobs.

Comment: @vidu if you want to segment every dot you will need to segment to pixels level, to do that probably you will need to use Mask R-CNN (Instance segmentation,) or U-net  (Semantinc segmentation)

Comment: Thank you @Freddy. Is there any way to do it without training...I mean in a way of a rule-based approach?